# Access 2007 Mail Merge fails to Execute. ODBC error

Tags: ms-access-2007

I get the following error when trying to execute a `mail merge` from `access`.

```
Title: ODBC Microsoft Access Driver Login Failed<br>
Body: Could not find file: "E:\Ryan\Access Database.mdb"
```

The problem here is my database is called `fe.accdb` and it is located in `E:\Ryan\Access Database\fe.accdb` and I cant find any reference whatsoever to the path above in either Access or Word.

Any idea where this reference would be?

Comment: You say you are trying to execute a mailmerge from Access. Are you doing this by clicking Word Merge on the External data tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to you ODBC database is configured in your ODBC settings.  Where this is updated for Office 2007 depends if you have a 32 or 64 bit OS.

If you have a 32-bit OS use the Database Sources (ODBC) under Administrative Tools

If you have a 64-bit OS use Database sources (ODBC) from c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Office 2007 is a 32 bit application and can only read 32-bit ODBC data souces.  Using the settings under Administrative tools on a 64-bit machine sets ODBC for 64-bit applications.  Confusing I know.

Here's one reference on this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976